# grouping multi-dimensional array in PHP

Tags: php

I have a multi-dimensional array, and I want to group it by org and then by dept.  I have the first level of grouping working:

```
   $groups = array();
   foreach($inv_h as $item) {
       $groups[$item['org']][] = $item;
   }
```

How do I achieve the second level of grouping?

Comment: If these values come from a database it's much easier to sort them with an `ORDER BY` clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly then it's as simple as repeating what you've already done for the second tier of the array:

```
$groups = array();
foreach($inv_h as $item) {
    $groups[$item['org']][$item['dept']][] = $item;
}
```

That should give you an array that looks like this:

```
groups = array(
    org1 => array(
        dept1 => array(results...),
        dept2 => array(results...)
    ),
    org2 => array(
        dept3 => array(results...),
        dept4 => array(results...)
    )
)
```